# Terraform tries to change to a helm_release resource version that does not exist in my code

Tags: terraform

Terraform is trying to change a version (0.2.2) of my helm_release resource but this version are not in my code neither in Terraform state:

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.14.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.20.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/helm v1.3.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes v1.13.3
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v3.0.0

$ terraform plan
...
...

  # module.k8s_cluster.helm_release.oauth_proxy will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "helm_release" "oauth_proxy" {
        id                         = "oauth"
        name                       = "oauth"
      ~ version                    = "3.2.0" -> "0.2.2"
        # (25 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

Coud you help me, please? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There were depreacated Helm repositories on my code. I changed it and now it's working.

Comment: Thank you, changing the stable repo to `https://charts.helm.sh/stable` worked for me too.